# Can I inject an Angular 2 component inside ViewChild instead of after?

Tags: angular

I have [this plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/BtCexy7FO3gLrg2SLADl/) demoing dynamic component injection. The problem is when I have the following....

```
template: `
  <div>
    <div #body class="body"></div>
  </div>
`,
```

I would like it to inject **INSIDE** the body div, however, it appends the component **AFTER** the div.

So instead of...

```
<div>
  <div></div>
  <my-app-2>
    <div>
      <h2>Hello Angular2</h2>
    </div>
  </my-app-2>
</div>
```

I want...

```
<div>
  <div>
    <my-app-2>
      <div>
        <h2>Hello Angular2</h2>
      </div>
    </my-app-2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know I could do something like this...

```
template: `
  <div>
    <div class="body">
      <div #body>
    </div>
  </div>
`,
```

But it there a way to do this without the extra div tag?

Comment: No, that's not possible. If you want to insert it inside, you need a `ViewContainerRef` from "inside"

Comment: What about adding a class to the injected component?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with that. Do you mean a CSS class? I don't see what you could do with a class. It's how `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` works - components are added as siblings.

Comment: @Jackie, you can read about DOM manipulation in angular [here](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02#.thw3avf8u)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks what I meant was adding a class to `my-app-2` so it would be something like `<my-app-2 class="body">` but I am thinking the more verbose way of adding the extra element is going to be the only answer.

Comment: That's what I meant. No, this won't help.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Go ahead and explain this in an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it there a way to do this without the extra div tag?

yes, you can use `ng-container` element:

```
<div class="body"><ng-container #body></ng-container></div>
```

it's represented as a comment inside the DOM, and hence you won't have an extra element in your DOM

check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gNXXxxj5zhbOjknOeTAe?p=preview)

Comment: So in this case there won't be the ng-container tag still after the component is injected? I just thought that was for transpiling and I have a different component rendered every time a selection is changed.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work https://embed.plnkr.co/GjY55AFSeirJQmcotVNP/ can you provide a plunker of what you mean?

Comment: @Jackie, you need to use `ng-container`, not `ng-content`. check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gNXXxxj5zhbOjknOeTAe?p=preview)

Comment: Dope! Thanks for that!

Comment: did you notice the errors in console though? Should I worry about them?

Comment: please update your plunker you are using the wrong life cycle https://plnkr.co/edit/fsylSn3HEIpipA9VLYio?p=preview https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10762

Answer (score 1):

`ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` only allows to add as sibling of the target element. If you want to add an element as child, the target needs to be a child of that element.

There were lots of discussions about that but I didn't get the impression this will change.

Comment: Despite what I said, after getting it to work this afternoon and seeing that it wouldn't include another element in rendering I am accepting the other answer. I still think your's should be regarded as the most 'official'